# How to create an associative array from more than two columns fetched from a sql query in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to fill an associative array with values from a fetched sql query, 
I've used this before for just two columns:

```php
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res1)){
    $key_words[utf8_encode($row['word'])] = utf8_encode($row['replace']);
}
```

**Ouputs:**

```
Array ( 
    [à] => a 
    [á] => a 
    [â] => a 
    [ã] => a 
    [ä] => a 
    [ç] => c 
    [é] => e 
    [è] => e 
    [ê] => e
)
```

But now I need for more than two columns. something like this:

```php
$array = array( subject => key => group  subject => key => group )
```

**Is it possible ?**

**EDIT 2**
This code:

```php
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    $replace[] = $row;
}
```

outputs this result:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [ID] => 1 
        [mot] => � 
        [remplace] => a 
        [Type] => lettre 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [ID] => 2 
        [mot] => � 
        [remplace] => a 
        [Type] => lettre 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [ID] => 3 
        [mot] => � 
        [remplace] => a 
        [Type] => lettre 
    )
)
```

I want the same result but not with all the columns just 3.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [mot] => � 
        [remplace] => a 
        [Type] => lettre 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [mot] => � 
        [remplace] => a 
        [Type] => lettre 
    ) 
    [2] => Array (  
        [mot] => � 
        [remplace] => a 
        [Type] => lettre 
    )
)
```

Comment: Please show us a proper example of the array you want to build. They way you've written it is a bit unclear

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Done.

Comment: That's not a valid array syntax though. If a key has a string as a value, it can't also have a sub array. One key can only have one value (the value could be an array with more values though). Try to create the array in PHP to see if it is valid or not. Then, when you've found the format you want, show us that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm sorry I add the ' ' just to clarify that it's a seperated value, I corrected it.

Comment: Arrays are key/value pairs. That means that `['à' => 'a']` is valid, but `['à' => 'a' => 'word']` isn't. That would require `a` to be both a string _value_ and an array index at the same time. That's just not possible. I would recommend you to [read through the manual about arrays.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you please read my new edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can get that result.

#### Using SQL

Since you seem to be fetching the data from a database, the best would be if you just selected the columns you want.

If you have this today:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

Change it to:

```
SELECT mot, remplace, Type FROM ...
```

Now `$row` will just contain those three values and you can use the code you have:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    $replace[] = $row;
}
```

#### Using PHP

If you, for what ever reason, don't want to limit the columns you fetch, you can just use the columns you want using PHP inside the loop:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    $replace[] = [
         'mot'      => $row['mot'],
         'remplace' => $row['remplace'],
         'Type'     => $row['Type'],
    ];
}
```

Both the above solutions should give you the result you want.